# Microphone buffer in NAudio C#

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I set sample rate on microphone(NAudio.WaveIn) 44100Hz. But when I use WaveInDataAvailible(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e). In e.Buffer I have 4410, instead of 44100 elements. Why this take me 10 times less measurement?

Answer (score 5):

That's because your buffer size is 50ms. Each buffer contains 2205 samples, and because they are 16 bits (2 bytes) each, there are 4410 bytes in your buffer.

Comment: If I use 8 bits, I have 4410 bytes buffer too. Naudio gives me buffer in 100ms?

Comment: Yes, the number of buffers and buffer durations are configurable using the DesiredLatency and NumberOfBuffers properties. Usually you have two buffers, so if your latency as 200ms, there would be two 100ms buffers.